# Ionic 4 ngOnInit is not called after navigate

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am new to ionic angular and working on a tutorial.

For better understanding, let say there is page A and B.

Below is the code of page B

**pageB.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsService } from '../news.service'
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-news-single',
  templateUrl: './news-single.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news-single.page.scss'],
})
export class NewsSinglePage implements OnInit {

  article: any;

  constructor(private newsService: NewsService, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ngOnInit")

    if(!this.newsService.currentArticle) {
      this.router.navigate(['/news']);
    }
    this.article = this.newsService.currentArticle;
  }

}
```

**pageB.html**

```
<ion-card class = "ion-margin-vertical">
      <img [src] = "article.urlToImage"/>
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-title>{{article.title}}</ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>

      <ion-card-content>

      {{article.description}}
      </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Here is the problem.

When i refresh on page B, **ngOninit()** is called.

Since **this.newsService.currentArticle** become undefined, it navigates back to **page A**.

Then when i navigate from **page A** to **page B**, **ngOninit()** is not called and **article** is 
still undefined.

I have tried to use **ionviewwillenter()** and it works with error.

Probably not a good practice because i insert data after component is created.

I hope I have made my issue clear.

Now, I am not sure its a bug or not because I don't fully understand how angular works in terms of life cycle hooks and how ionic use angular to make it work.

I have few questions now.

1. Is it a good practice to put data inside service since it become undefined after refreshing ??
2. How could i handle data during refresh ??

Thank you in advance.

---

Edit

After i use **ionViewWillEnter** to load data same as **ngOninit**,

the article is shown with error shown.

This error happens when i make the following action.

Refresh on Page B -> navigate to page A -> click to navigate to page B

[image: Here is the Error]

Answer (score 3):

**ngOnInit()** will run the first time the page has been opened

```
ngOnInit() {
   // Actions
}
```

**ionViewWillEnter()** will run every time the page is navigated to, just before the page is opened, good for preloading stuff.

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
   // Actions
}
```

**ionViewDidEnter()** will run every time the page is navigated to

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
   // Actions
}
```

*Note: The lettering is case sensitive*

Answer (score 2):

You can use IonViewDidEnter life cycle hook to call the service on page B.

Comment: @Xd. If this helped you solve your problem then please accept it as an answer.

Comment: When i call service using IonViewDidEnter, error still exists.
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'urlToImage' of undefined`

Comment: I have added the photo for better understanding.

Comment: Make sure to console your article variable after calling the service and check it's not undefined or null then create a new string variable e.g. imgUrl = "" & assign (imgUrl = this.article.urlToImage). Then assign this variable to src directive ([src] = "imgUrl")